# Mysql optimization operator 'I N'

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query.
I want to optimization this query,because it takes more then 4.sec

```
![SELECT clerk_id, COUNT(*) AS num
        FROM `note`
    WHERE note.id IN (
        SELECT note.id
            FROM `note`
                LEFT JOIN conn ON conn.contract_id = note.id
                WHERE `type` <>4 AND `type` <>6 AND `cancelled` =0 AND `ebill` <> '' AND activated_datetime > '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND activated_datetime >= '2011-06-13 00:00:00' AND activated_datetime <= '2011-06-21 23:59:59' AND clerk_code LIKE 'S%' 
    )
    GROUP BY clerk_id][1]
```

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write your query as a single one like this:

```
SELECT clerk_id, COUNT(*)
            FROM `contracts`
                LEFT JOIN contract_connections ON contract_connections.contract_id = contracts.id
                WHERE `type` <>4 AND `type` <>6 AND `cancelled` =0 AND `ebill` <> '' AND activated_datetime >= '2011-06-13 00:00:00' AND activated_datetime <= '2011-06-21 23:59:59' AND clerk_code LIKE 'S%' GROUP BY clerk_id
```

Please check and see if it returns the same thing and if performance improves

Comment: I removed the condition `AND activated_datetime > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` which is covered by `activated_datetime >= '2011-06-13 00:00:00'`

Comment: Thanks for help.I had a different results(Not the same results.)

Comment: That is weird - is there difference in the number of records returned, the name of the columns, or where?

Comment: I added an image of results in my question.

Comment: I say its weird, because in the inner query you mainly only set the where clause, for the outer one. Are you sure the DB data did not change between queries? maybe you should add some stricter ORDER BY clause to see if the data really is different, and not just presented differently

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT clerk_id, COUNT(*) AS num
        FROM `contracts`
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
            FROM contract_connections
                WHERE `type` <>4 AND `type` <>6 AND `cancelled` =0 AND `ebill` <> '' AND activated_datetime >= '2011-06-13 00:00:00' AND activated_datetime <= '2011-06-21 23:59:59' AND clerk_code LIKE 'S%' 
                AND contract_connections ON contract_connections.contract_id = contracts.id
    )
    GROUP BY clerk_id
```

In case you have an index on the type column you could benefit from it changing your WHERE clause from

```
WHERE type <>4 AND type <>6
```

To

```
WHERE (type<4 OR type=5 OR type>6)
```

Also remove

```
activated_datetime > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Since you already have

```
activated_datetime >= '2011-06-13 00:00:00'
```